# Какая разница между конфигурационными файлами my.ini и my.cnf?

Tags: mysql

Какая разница между конфигурационными файлами *my.ini* и *my.cnf*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

в актуальных версиях *mysql*, как видно из [документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html), в разных операционных системах дело обстоит немного по-разному.

1. в *ms/windows*:

   1. сервер просматривает несколько каталогов (`%PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\` (для версии `5.7`), `%WINDIR%\`, `C:\`, `BASEDIR\`) в поисках **как** `my.ini`, **так** и `my.cnf`
   2. клиент просматривает дополнительно файл `%APPDATA%\MySQL\.mylogin.cnf`
2. в *unix*-подобных:

   1. сервер просматривает несколько каталогов (`/etc/`, `/etc/mysql/`, `SYSCONFDIR/`, `$MYSQL_HOME/`) в поисках **только** `my.cnf`
   2. клиент просматривает дополнительно файлы `~/.my.cnf` и `~/.mylogin.cnf` (каталог `$MYSQL_HOME/`, как написано в документации, клиент игнорирует)

Answer (score 1):

Это фактически одно и тоже

`.ini` для `Windows`

`.cnf` для `Linux`

Comment: согласно [документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html), ответ, мягко говоря, не совсем верен.